# Does Jetty have a way to PRE-pend folders to an war's classpath?

Tags: configuration, jetty, classpath

I have an app.war which contains app.conf file which I load using ClassLoader.getResource(...) all works well in development, in production I would like to place a different kind of app.conf file which will contain secret database passwords, etc AHEAD of the bundled app.conf file in the war's classpath.  Is there a way to do it in Jetty ?